# Combine multiple lists resulting from a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dataframe

I am parsing over elements from multiple html.

I am getting the answer in form of multiple lists.

Here is part of my code:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    r = driver.get(row['post'])                               
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")
    records = []  
    comm = [r.nextSibling for r in soup.find_all('div', 
    class_=re.compile('_2b05'))]
    data = [''.join(i.stripped_strings) for i in comm if i]
    records.append(data)
    print(records)



    >>>> [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']] [['x', 'y']]
```

This formula runs under for loop. 
For some reason it doesn't append all lists into the records list. I need to combine all the lists of 'records' into one DataFrame - OR - if possible- all the elements of both lists into a DataFrame.

I tried:

```
items = list(set(chain.from_iterable(records)))
```

and

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'comment': list(item for item in 
itertools.chain.from_iterable(records))})
```

Both results are printed as two separate DataFrames, when I want them to be combined into only one DataFrame that I can transfer to csv.

Comment: I tried with `records = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['X', 'Y']]`, and your solution works. Can you explain the problem detailed?

Comment: I just modified my question. the above code is under a for loop. But still can't understand why records is [['x','y','z']] and  [['a','b','c']] instead of ['x','y','z', 'a','b','c']

Comment: Could you show `records`'s content as a code?

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved using a function `from_records`
For example:

```
>>> records= [['a','b','c'],['x','y']]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(records)
>>> df
   0  1     2
0  a  b     c
1  x  y  None
```

### Updated code

```
>>> records= [[['a','b','c']],[['x','y']]]
>>> for i,item in enumerate(records):
...     if i==0:
...             df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(item)
...     else:
...             df1 = df1.append(item, ignore_index=True)
... 
>>> df1
   0  1    2
0  a  b    c
1  x  y  NaN
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: records is under a for loop, so it give me the result into two separate lists that look like this : = [['a','b','c'] [['x','y']] so unfortunately your answer can't work